# Signed lease but no money or key exchange, it is binding

Tags: property

I signed a lease for a house sight unseen as I did a Skype walk through and saw pictures, so I liked and agreed on the house base on word of mouth terms from the agent. I get to the house and it is not at all like the pictures and the stairwell in the house is a huge safety hazard for children. I refused to move into the house based on safety reasons. I have no signed contract from the landlord either. Is this legally binding?

Comment: You do or do not have a signed lease on paper? You do or not have verbal lease agreement?

Comment: You say you signed a lease, but you also say you have no signed contract from the landlord. I'm not sure how to reconcile those statements. Do you mean to say that you signed the lease but the landlord didn't?

Answer (score 4):

You inspected the property online and based on that inspection you signed the lease.

**You have a legally binding contract.**

Now,

> it is not at all like the pictures

How? I mean, are these pictures of a different house? If that is so then your contract is void for fraud. However, if the pictures are of the actual house and you just imagined from them that the house would be other than it is then tough luck for you.

> the stairwell in the house is a huge safety hazard for children

OK.

Does it comply with relevant building codes? If not then the landlord needs to bring it up to standard: you cannot walk away from the contract.

Is it in need of repair? If so, the landlord needs to repair it: you cannot walk away from the contract.

If it is compliant and in good repair and *you* think it is a hazard notwithstanding then *you* need to manage that hazard: this is not the landlords problem.

> I refused to move into the house

That's fine: so long as you keep paying the rent there is no obligation on you to move in.

If you stop paying the rent then it would appear that you have repudiated the contract and the landlord can sue you for damages - probably the costs of finding a new tenant and the rent up until that tenant takes over.